# SharePoint Blank Page

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, multi-tenancy

This entire week I countered a Blank page problem in my SP environment.
Some sites and Central admin returns blank page.

I checked all of below items

1. loop back was correctly configured
2. Browser work correctly
3. IIS authentication does not change

What happened to my SharePoint? Everything was working correctly till last week.

My SharePoint working in Multi-Tenant mode.

Thanks all

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post it as a comment. Have you tried running the SharePoint configuration wizard ?

Comment: What is MT mode means? Are u accessing sites from server or pc? Is it for everything or only for few sites / pages? Is it fresh installation or did you apply any patch?

Comment: But what is maintenance mode means, everybody definition is little different so that's why I asked before recommend any steps

Comment: @Karthik : no ... it's production environment and try to found problem at first

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE : MT means Multi-Tenant mode and just 4 of 100 sites plus central administration

Comment: Are 4 sites with the same web app where other sites working? How many wfe? On which server central admin is hosted wfe or app servers?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE : all sitess in same Web App and 2 WFE 2 APP and hosting is in WFE

Answer (score 4):

Thanks  a lot guys 
I found the problem inside of SharePoint root folder .
We support two kind of languages in our farm . This problem happened for English pages and Central administration , I used ULC Viewer app and I realized one of files doesn't exist in root folder , so I copied from SharePoint Application server and pasted in SharePoint Web and problem fixed .

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

this happened to us as well. It seems to be because we had Trend Micro Anti-Virus which quarantined the initstrings.js file required by SharePoint. After releasing the file from quarantine, everything backup. Remember to add the file to exclusion list in Trend Micro, otherwise it will quarantine it again. more here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/5gs2gv/anyone_else_also_affected_by_a_deleted/